# What is meant by $\operatorname{Tor}(P,K)$ for $P$ a left $R$-module?

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, local-rings

Let $R$ be a finite dimensional algebra over a field $K$.

Suppose there is a two-sided ideal $I$ of $R$ such that

(a) $R=K\oplus I$;

(b) $I$ is nilpotent.

**Question**

If $P$ is a left $R$-module, how does one define $\operatorname{Tor}_{i}^{R}(P,K)?$

I saw this done in a book (J-P Serre's *Galois Cohomology*) without comment. So, I suppose he is viewing $P$ as a right $R$-module somehow. (In the book he also supposes it is a finitely generated left $R$-module, but I think this is not used at this point).

One idea is to define the right $R$-multiplication by
\begin{equation}
p\cdot r=(r+I)p,
\end{equation}
that is, we quotient $r$ to its 'field representative' and view it inside $R$.

Looks like the properties hold and it is compatible with the left $R$-module structure (in the sense that it becomes a $R-R$ bimodule).

Is this it? Or maybe its a typo and it should be a right $R$-module?

It's also weird because later on he writes $P/IP$, suggesting that indeed $P$ is a left $R$-module. How is this done?

I thank in advance for the help.

Comment: $R/I$ is  still an $R$-module and it is isomorphic as a vector space to $K$. That's enough. I don't see why the fact $I$ is nilpotent should be relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. $I$ being nilpotent is used later for Nakayama's Lemma and other purposes in the book so indeed it does not look relevant. What I was wondering was if this property somehow could be used to naturally induce a right $R$-module structure on a left $R$-module. But as you say, unlikely; probably not. I really believe this is a typo in the book, and Tor should've been written as $\operatorname{Tor}_{R}^{i}(K,P)$. Then everything works out fine. I checked a lot of homological algebra books and couldn't find anything related.